# game of live motion - how cells get on new places

Tags: javascript, jquery

at the moment i am coding conways game of life with javascript. as i know there are this rules:

- Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies, as if caused
  by under-population.
- Any live cell with two or three live neighbours
  lives on to the next generation.
- Any live cell with more than three
  live neighbours dies, as if by overcrowding.
- Any dead cell with
  exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell, as if by
  reproduction.

i dont know the rule how new cells appear or how the motion is made. the rules only say that the cells on their position either stay oder die, but how the motion gets in their?
after which rule new cells are born on new places?

Comment: Cells don't move. They are born or die in place, depending on their surroundings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing 'moves' but if a pattern later recurs in a different position it can be seen as having moved. 
The simplest pattern that 'moves' in this way is the humble glider:

[image: Glider]

If you apply the propagation rule you described to this pattern then in four generations the pattern will recur one down and one to right of its current position. Obviously by induction, if you continue the pattern will appear to 'glide' across the grid forever.

If you can't be bothered to do that by hand watch this step-by-step rule-by-rule animation:

[image]

Comment: yes i mean that apearing on an other position. okay i understand it now. every "empty cell" counts as dead cell which transforms into living cells. thank you!